# Indy documentation

Tags: c++builder, indy10, c++builder-xe

I think to start using Indy to replace the old and deprecated TSocket delphi component.

Indy seems to be a very rich collection of components but I have found no good documentation about it.
The only docs I found are both old or empty template without usefull info .

Can someone tell me where can I found some good documentation abou Indy 10 ?

Regards, Enzo

Answer (score 1):

the documentation for Indy is all here: http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/docs/index.en.aspx
in some cases it's less than detailed enough, but developers of indy do answer questions on stackoverflow ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this myself some time ago - I still use TServerSocket and TClientSocket although you have to install them yourself. I struggled to find documentation also, but I did come across a lot of info for Indy sockets  (enough to convince me to stick with TSockets anyway) on the embarcadero developer forums when considering the same path that you are now intending to take (I am assuming you have access to these if you are using c++Builder-XE like myself, so maybe try there if you have no luck here).

Comment: Thanks for the advise mathematician1975, but I was also looking for something like a real documentations.

Comment: yeah i figured as much - just thought i would throw it in there. good luck with it - i had none!! makes you realise how few people use embarcadero.

Comment: I am using XE2 and the documentation for Indy10 is installed in the help

Comment: The documentation installed with the help is very, very, very poor.  I need something better than that for work.